# How to Clone Ubuntu installed on USB stick onto PC HDD?

Tags: installation, usb, clone

I'we allready have a USB stick with Ubuntu installed. I'm running ubuntu from the USB stick so that I can bring it with me and plug it into different computers and boot my allready tweaked and customized ubuntu that contains all the tools I need.

Since nothing about ubuntu seems impossible; HOW do I install ubuntu on a PC's HDD, containing all the data, settings, apps etc. from my USB stick?

In advance; thanks

---

EDIT::

---

The PC I transfered on to is a laptop running windows 8. I've used gparted liveCD to create a 55GB ext4 expanded partition(don't know if it need to be an expanded or primary, but the partition on my USB is "expanded"), 
and a 5GB linux-swap partition. I've managed to clone the 55GB partition from my USB stick to the HDD. I expect that the linux-swap partition doesn't need to be cloned?!

After some playing with BootRepair, I now have a bootable "fully" working system. But it's slower and jittery now while running from the HDD. It pauses a lot, booting takes approximately 3-4 times longer than when i ran it from the USB. Even win8 runs a lot smoother on this machine.

Should this be the case??

Answer (score 0):

[Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) should do the trick